# Method return type like Generic Class Type

Tags: c#, generics

Is possible set method return type, like type to generic class  ?

I have Generic Class:

```
    class Generic<T>
    {
        public static DataSet test(T input)
        {
         //Some logic...
        }
    }
```

Another Class, where i call my generic class.

It works for this examples:

```
Generic<int>.test(10);
```

But if i want to call different methods, with complex unknown date types, i don't know how i put their date type like Generic Type.

For Example

```
var data = Data.GetData(); // return List<string,int>
var data2 = Data.GetData2() // return Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>
```

I try use method GetType, for get returns method type, something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
Generic<data.GetType()>.test(data);
```

Is it possible, something like this ?

Comment: What will `test` do with `T` you have no restrictions on it and you don't use it for the return type. Why not just make the class non generic and just do `dynamic test(object input)`?

Comment: `test<T>(T input)`

Comment: In the final i want to transform this result List, Tuples to DataSet, i put it here dynamic only generaly, but i want to return DataSet.

Comment: Could you just change from using a generic class to a generic method? So you instead have `Test<T>(T input)`? Its hard to tell what your generic class and method are actually doing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't specify the generic type at runtime without reflection, but there may be other ways to solve your problem.  You *could* put the generic constraint on the method instead of the class:

```
class Generic
{
    public static dynamic Test<T>(T input)
    {
     //Some logic...
    }
}
```

which then can be inferred from the input type:

```
Generic.Test(data);
```

Comment: Oh, that's it. I'm new in Generic Types and i thought, that i must have a generic class, when i want to work with generic methods. Thanks.

Comment: @tomas Nope - only when you want the generic type to apply to the entire class.

Answer (score 0):

Return Type of a function is known in compile time.
Therefore if I understood your question correctly what you're asking for isn't possible. **TL;DR You can't set return type in runtime.**